# Get binary Matrix of current figure in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, binary, figure

I am currently trying to generate a binary matrix of a animated figure for each frame. I use the matplotlib animation package to create a animation of moving dots in a 10 x 10 figure.

```
def animate(i):
    for dot in dots:
        dot.move()
    d.set_data([dot.x for dot in dots],
               [dot.y for dot in dots])

    return d,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=1)
```

[image]

I know I could save the fig as **a .png** and load it again to get the RGB and then generate the binary matrix by thresholds, but this cant be a proper soloution.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: If you have the raw data (to even make the animation), why can't you just use that data?

Comment: i want to use the binary Matrix (0 for White spot and 1 for black spot) data as Input of a neuronal Network. In reality i don't have the Position of the dots and there is no possibility of detecting the position. But i have an Image of the dots moving which i am taking with a camera. If i use the raw data i would somehow cheat and could not use the NN in reality